# Yii. Post request comes empty

Tags: php, post, yii

I'm trying to run another developer's application written in Yii. 
There is a problem when sending a POST request in the form of authorization.

The request goes to: `/index.php?r=site/login`

But in **SiteController actionLogin()** comes an already empty post.

At first I thought that the problem is in the settings of the PHP, but apparently this is not the case. 
Because I tried to see what comes in `$_POST` in the `index.php` in the root of the site and then in the onBeginRequest methods and `onEndRequest in CApplication.php.` There the data in `$_POST` are visible.

Are there any ideas why it could happened?

Comment: Does your controller have any `beforeAction`?

Comment: @D3ad L0cK, no, there is no beforeAction in SiteController

Comment: So should be fine. You may print out in different controller or why don't you try again with Yii way to print out request. You can reference it from https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests

Comment: Tried to write these lines in actionLogin in SiteController: $request = Yii::$app->request;                                                                                                                                                  
print_r($request); 
exit;

but got this message http://prntscr.com/kzq52e

Comment: tried to catch POST in `CUrlManager parseUrl` - also empty (

Comment: update your question and add the code related  to the action that  send the post and the action that receive the post

Comment: @scaisEdge the post is sending from an auth form. The action that receive the post already has empty POST on the start lines of the action. The problem seems in between.